# How to target props of a component already nested inside another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a different component in my App.js based on an OnClick placed in a button nested inside my Home component. Essentially I want the Home component to initially be rendered and then my "Restaurants" component to replace it  when I click on the "Explore Restaurants" (which changes the state from true to false) button which is nested in my Home component. I am new to react so I'm sure there is an easy way to do this but I'm feeling a bit lost.

```
Here is the code

**App.js:**
import React, {useState} from "react";
import './App.css';
import Home from "./home"
import Footer from "./footer"
import Header from "./header"
import Resturants from "./resturants";


function App() {
var [count, setCount] = useState(false);
return (
    <div>
    <Header/>
    {count ? <Home /> : <Resturants/>  }
    <Footer/> 
     </div>

  
  );
}

export default App;


**Home.js**
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Button from "./button";
import {Stack} from "react-bootstrap";
import Promotions from './promotions'

//This component purely renders the home page when the user opens the app.

function Home (){

 function changePage (){
 setCount(count = true)
  } 
 
 return (
 <Stack>
 <Promotions />
 <Button className ="homeButtons" buttonText="Login" />
 <Button className ="homeButtons" buttonText="Signup" />
 <Button onClick ={changePage} className ="homeButtons" buttonText="Explore Resturants" />
 </Stack>
) 
}

export default Home


**Button.js**
import React from "react"

function Button (props){
return  (<button onClick={props.onClick} style={props.style} className ={props.className} type = {props.type}> {props.buttonText} </button> 
)
}

export default Button
```

Comment: `function changePage(){ setCount(true)  } `

Comment: You'll also have to pass setCount inside props to Home

Comment: Inside App.js `{count ? <Home setCount={setCount} /> : <Resturants/>  }` and on Home `function Home ({setCount}){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the `setCount` method down to the `Home` component as a prop:

```
function App() {
  var [count, setCount] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {count ? <Home setCount={setCount} /> : <Resturants />}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then, retrieve it in the `Home` component:

```
function Home({ setCount }) {
  function changePage() {
    setCount((oldCount) => !oldCount);
  }
```